# Taking curl numerically of a Hamiltonian writtein in Fourier space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, computational-physics, simulations

I have a Hamiltonian given in 2D k-space
$$
H = \sum_{\vec k}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_k^+&b_k^+
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
h_{11}&h_{12}\\ h_{21}&h_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_k\\b_k
\end{bmatrix} \tag{1}
$$
the quantities $h_{ij}=h_{ij}(k_x,k_y)$ i.e. depend upon $k_x,k_y$. And a current operator is defined as
$$
J(\vec k) = -e\hat v_x = -\frac{e}{\hbar}\frac{\partial H}{\partial_{k_x}} \tag{2}
$$
I want to calculate the quantity
$$
A = \nabla_{\vec k} \times J(\vec k)
\tag{3}
$$
I can numerically find $J(\vec k)$ for each point $k_x,k_y$ of Fourier space. But to find curl of $J(\vec k)$, I need $\hat k_x$ direction and $\hat k_y$ direction component of $J(\vec k)$ i.e. of course
$$
J(\vec k) = J_x \hat k_x + J_y \hat k_y \tag{4}
$$
Is there any way to find these $J_x$ and $J_y$ components from $J(\vec k)$?

I see, in the following publication they calculate curl of $J(\vec k)$ (Eq. 13 and Figure 4), if I am not doing it right, what's the right way?

> [Origin of the Magnetic Spin Hall Effect: Spin Current Vorticity in
> the Fermi Sea](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.13375.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:
By calculating $(2)$, I actually get only $J_x$. To get $J_y$, I should calculate $-ev_y = -\frac{e}{\hbar}\frac{\partial H}{\partial_{k_y}}$. And together with $J_x$ and $J_y$, I can calculate curl using $(4)$ and $(3)$. (I used MATLAB's curl() function to get numerical curl).